# Custom tooltip on TreeNode AntDesignPro

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

I have a line code:

`<TreeNode title={"abc"} ...>`

Problem: When i hover mouse to this element, it display default tooltip text is title, in my example is "abc".

=> expected: 
i want custom my text in tooltip, not default.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi
> I solved it this way

```
<TreeNode value="parent 1-0" title={
     <Tooltip placement="right" title={"abc"}>
          <div style={{width: "100%"}}>abc</div>
     </Tooltip>
}/>
```